# Usamah ibn Zayd RA praying at the grave of the Prophet SAW

Tags: hadith, authenticity

> Aboo Ya'la has told us that he said that Aboo Musa Muhammad ibn Muthana has said that Wahab ibn Jurair said that his father said I have heard Muhammad ibn Ishaq talking from Salih ibn Kiyas from Ubaid Allah ibn Abdullah that he said, ''I saw Usamah ibn Zayd praying at the grave of the Prophet (saw). Marwan ibn Al-Hakam entered and said: "Do you pray to a grave?" So he (Zayd) said: "I love him!" So (Marwan) said some repulsive words. So he turned and Usama walked and said: "O Marwan! You have hurt me, and I have heard Prophet (saw) saying, ''Allah (swt) hates the vile, the doer of obscene act and you are vile and a doer of obscene act."
>
> Source: Saheeh ibn Hibban. Vol. 12, Pg. # 506, H. # 5694.

Is the Hadith above authentic? It contradicts the Prophetic prohibition of praying at graves. Could it be that Usama ibn Zayd RA was unaware of said prohibition?

Comment: Is there a reason why my queries stopped being addressed?

Comment: Just for your information -a first impression- among the narrators is Muhammad ibn Ishaaq who is discussed among scholars. And according to dorar there should be an error in this narrator list as what you've quoted as  "Salih ibn Kiyas from Ubaid Allah ibn Abdullah" should rather be Salih ibn Kissan 'Ubaid ibn 'Abdullah so it seems one person! And this corresponds to the fact that Muhammad ibn Ishaaq is a later at-tabi'y who may have met some Sahabah who reached a high age, but  would transmit from most Sahabah via an intermediate.

Comment: I meant no disrespect. I understand that most of us are busy with our lives. I'll have you know that I've retracted those questions and returned to asking for simple source identifications, authentications and interpretations. It's just that most of the other queries are readily answered and mine's keep pending. If there's a problem with my questions then I'll edit or delete them. I apologise for any offenses.

Comment: It also sounds strange as Usamah ibn Zayd himself narrated a -sahih- hadith prohibiting prayer at graves. Yes but source identifications and authenticity require more research than others!

Comment: If anyone feels offended by my behavior then I apologise with full ikhlas. I'll lay low for a few weeks.

Comment: As for my earlier comment I must correct it and can now confirm that the narrator chain looks alright as Salih ibn Kissan and 'Ubaid Allah ibn 'Abdullah are indeed two different people (Tabi'yn) from Medina: Salih ibn Kissan was born 40 a.H. he was a teacher for the children of 'Umar ibn 'Abdal'aziz and ['Ubaid Allah ibn 'Abdullah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubayd-Allah_ibn_Abd-Allah) is one of the 7 known scholars from Medina and he was born during theCalifat of 'Umar ibn al-Khattab as a-Dhahabi has mentioned and ibn Kissan has narrated from him! The mistake should be a typo on dorar.

Comment: So is it safe to say that Usama RA was uninformed of the prohibition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116192/discussion-between-medi1saif-and-afiq).

Answer (score -3):

https://al-maktaba.org/book/33842/1022

Albani declared it weak. Put it into translate.google.com if you do not know arabic. May Allah bless you and keep us all steadfast. Ameen.